# How test a scroll from window event with Angular?

Tags: angular, scroll, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test this component:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  sticky: boolean = false;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ["$event"]) onScroll(event: Event) {
    let window = event.currentTarget as Window;
    console.log(window.scrollY);
    this.sticky = window.scrollY >= 30;
  }

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

and there is the test :

```
  it("onScroll_Down_StickyIsTrue", () => {

  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("scroll"));
  window.scrollTo(0 , 50);

    expect(component.sticky).toBeTrue();
  });
```

And I don't know why the window.scrollY still 0.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
it("onScroll_Down_StickyIsTrue", () => {
  component.onScroll({
    currentTarget: {
      scrollY: 31
    }
  } as any);
  expect(component.sticky).toBeTrue();
});
```

Comment: Indeed that works, just a question, why it doesn't work with the window.scrollTo(0 , 50); ?

Comment: EDIT: This could be already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385262/how-to-simulate-window-scrolling-in-a-angular-unit-test

Comment: Your tests do not automatically trigger the Angular lifecycle hooks that Angular does if up and running. So you have to trigger them yourself. That's why here you have to trigger the event as if it's been scrolled away.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but this is a Unit Test. I prefer to test a real scroll doing e2e. This was another way to test it, Maybe the link provided by you could be more Angular way